# Error inspecting states in the "s3" backend: NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist

Tags: terraform

I am running `terraform init` on my terraform modules folder and I am getting below.

```
Error inspecting states in the "s3" backend:
    NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist
    status code: 404, request id: 6667B0A661F9C62F, host id: 3mC8DNrS/gGHtp7mhVMRtpIUeMaNXs2cEozEY+akZf1ixFD6x2qQx7c3mX02M1BIbyfYowYt35s=
```

Comment: Does the bucket exist? Do the keys used by terraform have rights to the bucket? Are you using the right region for your bucket? There isn't much to go on here. What have you tried and whats the code look like?

Comment: Actually, the bucket exists and the key is also correct as well.

Comment: I had the same issue. Deleting the .terraform directory and running init again fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 43):

I was having the same issue.

Using aws command `aws s3 ls` and  `aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket-name`

I could list the content but was still having the same issue.

> Error inspecting states in the "s3" backend:
>       NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist
>       status code: 404, request id: xxxxx, host id: xxxxxx

Erased the `./terraform` directory and it fixed my issue.

Comment: Erasing ./terraform helped us out! Thanks kind stranger!

Comment: Holy ___ ! Erasing ./terraform helped us out! Thanks a lot. saved my day...

Comment: In my case I changed the terraform backend, moving to a different S3 bucket. Inside the `.terraform` directory, the `terraform.tfstate` file still listed the old bucket, editing that file then allowed `terraform init` to work successfully.

Comment: This also resolved  `Error inspecting states in the "s3" backend: AccessDenied` for me.  thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much, I was extremely frustrated with this!

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the similar issue as below

```
Error inspecting states in the "s3" backend:
    AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: XXXXXX, host id: XXXXX
```

And after removing the .terraform file it worked (In my case I was using Jenkins, so I have to remove it from Jenkins server's project directory and it worked for me). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In my case even when  I removed that `.terraform` as mentioned does not work, I have to add the profile in s3 backend module even profile exist in provider.

adding configuration might help others.

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = var.region
  profile = "myprofile"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    encrypt = true
    bucket  = "appname-terraform-state"
    region  = "ap-southeast-1"
    key     = "terraform.tfstate"
    profile = "myprofile"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case just remove all directory from terraform and again hit terraform init command via git, now working for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, please run

```
terraform init -reconfigure
```